# pyQt5 add multi image in same window

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5

I'm planning to create a music player with pyQt5, and it's kinda hard for beginner like me.Back to my question, i want to add 7 diffrent images: the first one its the album cover art and the rest of the image have an act like icons for song title, album, artists,...

But when I try this code

```
pic = QtGui.QLabel(self)
pic.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("Q107.png"))
pic.resize(250,80)
pic.move(20,90)
pic.show()


pic1 = QtGui.QLabel(self)
pic1.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("Q307.png"))
pic1.resize(250,80)
pic1.move(20,90)
pic1.show()
```

The program only display 1 image - the first image

Sorry for my bad English

Thanks for reading this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both images are at same position (20,90), so one image is hidden under the other. After changing the position of pic1, it is showing both images.

```py
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QLabel
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap

class App(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        pic = QLabel(self)
        pic.setPixmap(QPixmap("Q107.png"))
        pic.resize(250,80)
        pic.move(20,90)
        pic.show()

        pic1 = QLabel(self)
        pic1.setPixmap(QPixmap("Q307.png"))
        pic1.resize(250,80)
        pic1.move(20,190)
        pic1.show()

        self.show()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = App()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: output]

Comment: Thanks for your reply, after changing the position of other image, the second one still invisible.

Comment: Then, revise your Q107.png and Q307.png images. The program is currently working for me and showing two images after change pic1 to `pic1.move(20,190)`

Comment: Did you solve your problem? If not, can you post your images in the question?